# Why do people say "I like" not "I like it" when they like something?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Why do some people say "I like" not "I like it" when they like something? I have seen that on the internet and in person. Is it even grammatical?

Edit:

Editing by request
I have heard that bare "I like" as comments when they see something they think is nice they say "I like" and I have seen it on Facebook in pic comments someone would write a comments just saying " I like" also on informative postings. 
I hope this edition helps figuring this out.

Comment: In what context did you hear people say "I like"? Was it an answer to a question?

Comment: I have seen that as feedbacks in educational postings and picture comments on the famous FB.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez : Please edit your question to add an example. That would be helpful.

Comment: Ok I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To like is mostly used as a transitive verb, which means it needs an object. However, on the internet, people use "I like" in a comment to a post when they find it agreeable or enjoyable.

The reason why the object of to like is not required is it is already in the post. In other words, "I like" is short for "I like what you posted" or "I like what is in your post" as the below picture indicates.

[image]

Comment: I think this is it, Rathony, you got all at once. I like (:

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Thanks for your "I like". :-)

Comment: The usage of this construction is also probably heavily influenced by Facebook and its "like" button.

Comment: But it was spoken out loud before Facebook existed.